# setState doesn't apply changes to component state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

I use `react v16.0.0-alpha.6` and `react-native v0.44.2`.

I've encountered too weird situation.

State is changed with the code below. This is an expected result. It's OK.

```
// current this.state.searchInputValue is 'q' 
// coming searchInputValue is 'a' 
_handleSearchInputValueChanged = (searchInputValue) => {
    this.state.searchInputValue = searchInputValue
    // here searchInputValue of the state is 'a'
}
```

State is changed with the code below. This is an expected result too. It's OK.

```
// current this.state.searchInputValue is 'q' 
// coming searchInputValue is 'a' 
_handleSearchInputValueChanged = (searchInputValue) => {
    setTimeout(()=>this.setState({ searchInputValue }))
    // after running the setTimeout and async setState methods
    // searchInputValue of the state is 'a' 
}
```

However this normal usage of `setState` doesn't work

```
// current this.state.searchInputValue is 'q'
// coming searchInputValue is 'a'
_handleSearchInputValueChanged = (searchInputValue) => {
    this.setState({ searchInputValue })
    // after running async setState method
    // searchInputValue of the state is still 'q' 
}
```

I wonder that is there any chance to overcome this issue?

### Edit

I have edited my explanation to show my issue easily.
setState operation doesn't throw any error. Only it doesn't change the current value of the a state prop.

In the component that is encountered this issue on, two `eventListener`s and several `setState` are called depends on their works.
Even if `setState` methods is called on-and-on all of them should be run correctly, right. `setState` is just a function.

For now, I have to use `setTimeout(()=>this.setState({ searchInputValue }))` as a work around.

And this is the most weird issue on React-Native I encountered so far :)

I check `React` and `React-Native` repos if there is any issue about this. I could find nothing.

Also I upgraded `React` to `16.0.0-alpha.12` and `React-Native` to `0.46.4`. Unfortunately the issue continues.

Comment: Why are you using using `Object.assign` ? Have you tried to simply do : `this.setState({ searchInputValue });` ?

Comment: Antoine Grandchamp is correct. No need to use `Object.assign` because `setState` performs a [Shallow Merge](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper#shallow-merge).

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp I set the state for months in this way. Thank you for this clarification.

Answer (score 3):

The first two examples that you deem "normal" are both very bad practice.

1. You should never mutate a component's state using direct assignment (ie `this.state.* = ...`)
2. `setState` is already an asynchronous operation and has no reason/benefit of being wrapped in a `setTimeout` call.

If you are attempting to change a portion of the component state and refill with the rest of the existing values, then use this alternate definition of the function:

```
_handleSearchInputValueChanged = (searchInputValue) => {
  this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
    ...prevState,
    searchInputValue
  }))
}
```

If you are trying to perform an action after `setState` you can provide a `callback` argument after the `updater` argument. You can see an example of this in the [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) documentation. Considering `setState` is asynchronous, you will need to use a callback or a component's `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method to perform operations on state immediately following an update.

Comment: From the docs: [Do Not Modify State Directly](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly).

Comment: @KyleRichardson Was just about to update with them, thanks! :)

Comment: You're welcome! I was in the process of answering when you and Antoine answered / commented :)

Comment: Normal was a __wrong__ word. It had to be __expected__ :) The third one is a real normal usage. I used `setTimeout` as a clue for something I don't know.

Comment: @KyleRichardson thanks for your helps! I've tried to explain my issue more correctly. Sorry for late.

Comment: @m_callens thanks for your helps! I've tried to explain my issue more correctly. Sorry for late.

Comment: @efkan Try this to check if state is updating: `this.setState({ searchInputValue }, () => { console.log(this.state) })` here we're supplying a callback argument to be invoked once `setState` has completed.

Comment: @KyleRichardson , I'm trying it right now and it works as expected! I spent a half day and because of this I've upgraded RN and React libraries. I've encountered with a ton issue. I spent 2 and a half days because of this issue and now it seems corrected. And I don't know how. But I thank you a lot. Really...

Comment: @efkan you're very welcome. Glad you've got it working!